# C++: How to call a function whenever an element is added to a set?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I have two functions. The first one fills a set with elements:

```
void fill_set(set<string> & theset, int number)
```

where `number` is the number of elements to be put in the set.Then a function is applied to each element of the set.

```
set<string> myset;
vector<float> results;

fill_set(myset,1000000);
for (auto const & s : myset)
     results.push_back(func(s));
```

The problem is that it takes a long time for `fill_set` to finish so I'd like a way to apply `func` each time a new element is added to `myset`, achieving a partial parallelism. Is there any way to do this in C++?

Comment: Show us the real content of the set, and say what you really wish to do. Thus far your question has a trivial solution: there’s no need to use the set at all. You’re also presuming that the set-filling is slow, and I have a hunch that it isn’t, but the source of your data is slow to generate the elements for the set. Am I right?

Comment: @mojo That has nothing to do with parallelism though. The question is ill-formed at the moment.

Comment: The best solution depends at least in part on how `fill_set` works, and why it takes a long time to finish.

Comment: Seems like a task queue? Why not using an existing framework like TBB?

Comment: The need for the set is because the elements need to be unique. And yes, slow to generate the elements to fill the set. A task queue sounds like a good thing although I don't know much about.

Answer (score 0):

You should rework how your code works to be more abstract.

```
template<class T> using sink=std::function<void(T)>;
```

Now fillmset becomes:

```
void fill_set(sink<string> thesink, int number);
```

and instead of `theset.insert(foo)` you call `thesink(foo)`.

Then refactor:

```
set<string> myset;
vector<float> results;

fill_set([&](auto x){myset.insert(std::move(x));},1000000);
for (auto const & s : myset)
  results.push_back(func(s));
```

and refactor:

```
set<string> myset;
vector<float> results;

fill_set([&](auto s){
  auto worked = myset.insert(std::move(s));
  if(worked.second)
    results.push_back(func(s));
},1000000);
```

You can go further and make thread safe queues and worker threads and thread pools; but it all starts with abstracting out that set.